# gsub: remove till first occurence instead of last occurence of a given character in a line

Tags: awk, unix-text-processing

I have an html file which I basically try to remove first occurences of `<...>` with `sub`/`gsub` functionalities.

I used awk regex `.` `*` `+` according to match anything between `<` `>`. However first occurence of `>` is being escaped (?). I don't know if there is a workaround.

sample **input** `file.txt` *(`x` is added not to print empty)*:

```
<div>fruit</div></td>x
<span>banana</span>x
<br/>apple</td>x
```

**code**:

```
awk '{gsub(/^<.*>/,""); print}' file.txt
```

**current** output:

```
x
x
x
```

**desired** output:

```
fruit</div></td>x
banana</span>x
apple</td>x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, using `sub` substitute function of `awk` programing. Then substituting starting `<` till(using `[^>]` means till first occurrence of `>` comes) `>` including `>` with NULL in current line, finally print edited/non-edited line by `1`.

```
awk '{sub(/^<[^>]*>/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` here match values from 1st occurrence of `<` to till 1st occurrence of `>` and print the rest of line.

```
awk 'match($0,/^<[^>]*>/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***OR*** In case you have lines which are not starting from `<` and you want to print them also then use following:

```
awk 'match($0,/^<[^>]*>/){print substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);next} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it works. I will accept the answer. Furthermore, do you have any link/reference suggestion to study?

Comment: @AhmetSaidAkbulut, Your welcome, you could see section https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for detailed information of books links references, along with that you can check daily Q & A for `awk` tag for understanding it more, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

*However first occurence of `>` is being escaped (?).*

No, you got result as is due to that in GNU `AWK` as [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Leftmost-Longest.html) say

> `awk`(...)regular expressions always match the leftmost, *longest*
> sequence of input characters that can match

this is called *greedy* in other languages' regular expressions usage, so say for

```
<div>fruit</div></td>x
```

`/^<.*>/` does match

```
<div>fruit</div></td>
```

thus you end with `x`. In languages supporting so-called non-greedy matching you can harness it in such case, for example in ECMAScript

```
let str = "<div>fruit</div></td>x";
let out_str = str.replace(/^<.*?>/, "");
console.log(out_str);
```

output

```
fruit</div></td>x
```

As GNU `AWK` manual say in GNU `AWK` it is always longest (greedy), thus you have to use `[^>]` i.e. *all but `>`* to prevent match spanning from first `<` to last `>` which would contain `>` inside.